# Поехавшая вёрстка в блоке репутации в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Фраза *в лучших...* не входит в одну строку при 29+ символах в ней. А так как свёрстан блок репутации весьма специфично, то вторая строка вместо того, чтобы помещаться в свободное пространство между первой строкой и *Лучшая метка*, сдвигает первую строку вверх.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку исправил Nicolas Chabanovski ещё пару месяцев назад. [Новые строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266637?q=top%20**%24percentString%24%25**) нормально входят в отведённое им место:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> `top **$percentString$%** this quarter`
>   `в лучших **$percentString$%** за квартал`

> `top **$percentString$%** this week`
>   `в лучших **$percentString$%** за неделю`

> `top **$percentString$%** overall`
>   `в лучших **$percentString$%** за всё время`

> `top **$percentString$%** this month`
>   `в лучших **$percentString$%** за месяц`

> `top **$percentString$%** this year`
>   `в лучших **$percentString$%** за год`

Comment: Вы неправы. Добавьте еще немного текста через консоль разработчика и увидите описанное поведение.

Comment: @VenZell: разумеется, если добавить текста, то строка не влезет. Речь о том, что поменялся шаблон и теперь строки `в лучших $rate$% за $time$` всегда входят в отведённое место.

Comment: Хм, проверил для случая с `в лучших 10.81% за все время`. Все влезло. Похоже, вы все-таки правы.

Comment: @VenZell: вроде бы там такие случаи округляются. Дробные значения – только если меньше единицы. Добавил строки, чтобы было понятно, что и как исправлено.